# C# how to get values from appsettings.json

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract from appsettings.json

```
"BulkMailCodes": {
        "NcoaCorrectedCodes": {
             "A": "Full match",
            "91": "Matched despite missing secondary number",
            "92": "Matched despite extra secondary number"
        },
        "NcoaSuppressedCodes": {
            "0": "No matching address",
            "1": "New address is Outside US",
            "2": "No forwarding address",
            "3": "PO Box closed",           
        }
```

How can I get the key/value pairs for "BulkMailCodes":"NcoaCorrectedCodes" into a Dictionary or KeyValuePair object?

I have this class:

```
    class BulkMail
    {
        public static IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfig();
        Dictionary<string, string> ncoaCorrected, ncoaSuppressed;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BulkMail bulkMail = new BulkMail();
        }

        public BulkMail()
        {
            ncoaCorrected = configuration["BulkMailCodes: CassSuppressedCodes"];
            Console.WriteLine("NcoaCorrectedCodes: ");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ncoaCorrected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
            }


        }

        public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfig()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            return (builder.Build());
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ncoaCorrected = configuration.GetSection("BulkMailCodes:NcoaCorrectedCodes").GetChildren()
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

Console.WriteLine("NcoaCorrectedCodes: ");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ncoaCorrected)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
}
```

Comment: This worked, however the real source of my problem was the Copy to Output Directory in File Properties for appsettings.json defaults to 'Do Not Copy'.  I changed it to 'Copy always' and it worked instantly.  If this is a required setting, why it defaults to 'Do Not Copy' is beyond comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is bind it to an object of type Dictionary.
You will need to add a nugget package: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
You can do it like this:

```
      class BulkMail
      {
        public static IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfig();
        private Dictionary<string, string> ncoaCorrected = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private Dictionary<string, string> ncoaSuppressed = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          BulkMail bulkMail = new BulkMail();
        }

        public BulkMail()
        {
           configuration.GetSection("BulkMailCodes:NcoaCorrectedCodes").Bind(ncoaCorrected);
           configuration.GetSection("BulkMailCodes:NcoaSuppressedCodes").Bind(ncoaSuppressed);

          Console.WriteLine("NcoaCorrectedCodes: ");
          foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ncoaCorrected)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
          }

          Console.WriteLine("NcoaSuppressedCodes: ");
          foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ncoaSuppressed)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
          }

          Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfig()
        {
          var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
          return (builder.Build());
        }
      }
```